# 3 Phase Power Question Wording

Tags: three-phase, phase, line

I am running in to a problem when working on 3 phase problems. I don't really know how to determine if the voltage given in the question statement is the line or phase voltage.

> The magnitude of the phase voltage of an ideal balanced three-phase Y-connected source is 4000V. The source is connected to a balanced Y connected load through a distribution line that has an impedance of 1+j8 per line. The load impedance is 119+j27 per phase. Using the source voltage Van as the reference, find the following phasor quantities.

For me when I see the Van as reference I think that the 4000V is the phase voltage and the line voltage will be sqrt(3)*4000.

Am I right in this assumption?

Answer (score 1):

The quoted question clearly states that the phase voltage is 4000V. If the wording did not mention whether the voltage given is the phase voltage or line voltage, you would assume that it is the line voltage. For this question, Van can be assumed to mean the A phase to neutral voltage. In some other context, it might mean something else, but that would be pretty unusual.